# Access kafka on cloud from onprem K8

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, strimzi

I am trying to connect to kafka broker setup on azure aks from onprem rancher k8 cluster over internet . I have created a loadbalancer listener on azure kafka. it is creating 4 public ip's using azure load balancer service.

```
  - name: external
    port: 9093
    type: loadbalancer
    tls: true
    authentication:
     type: tls  
    configuration:
      bootstrap:
        loadBalancerIP: 172.22.199.99
        annotations:
          external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: bootstrap.example.com
          
      brokers:
      - broker: 0
        loadBalancerIP: 172.22.199.100
        annotations:
          external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: kafka-0.example.com
        
      - broker: 1
        loadBalancerIP: 172.22.199.101
        annotations:
          external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: kafka-1.example.com
        
      - broker: 2
        loadBalancerIP: 172.22.199.102
        annotations:
          external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: kafka-2.example.com

      brokerCertChainAndKey:
        secretName: source-kafka-listener-cert
        certificate: tls.crt
        key: tls.key
```

now to connect from onprem i have opened firewall for only bootstrap lb ip .My understanding is that bootstrap will inturn route the request to individual broker but that is not  happening. When i try to connect connection is established with bootstrap loadbalncer ip but after that i get timeout error .

```
2022-08-22 08:14:04,659 INFO Metrics reporters closed (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics) [kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1]
2022-08-22 08:14:04,659 ERROR Stopping due to error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed) [main] org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to connect to and describe Kafka cluster. Check worker's broker connection and security properties.
at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConnectUtils.lookupKafkaClusterId(ConnectUtils.java:70)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConnectUtils.lookupKafkaClusterId(ConnectUtils.java:51)
```

please let me know if i have to open firewall for individual brokers as well?

Comment: This is a bit confusing. 1) You talk about loadbalancers with public IPs, but isn't 172.22 in a private IP range? 2) The DNs names you give it have no meaning if you don't configure them as the advertised hostnames as well. External DNS might assign them to the IPs, but nobody will use them.  3) Yes, if you have any firewalls on the way, you will need to open them for all brokers. 4) You should probably start with a simple rpdocuer / consumer and not with Connect. They might make it easier to debug and analyze the issue.

Comment: You cannot use only a load balancer for connections. The brokers advertise their own addresses to all clients and clients need to connect to individual brokers.

Comment: @Jakub - i gave private ip's just for example , in actual config those are public ones.I will open firewall for all broker and try to test again . Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @Jakub - connectivity is working fine after opening firewall for all brokers .